# How to unseal a Vault in practice?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

It is possible to force that multiple keys have to be entered in order to unseal the vault. How does this work in practice? If someone has entered a key and there is another key required to unseal the vault should one ask a colleague to enter another key and how should this be done to prevent that colleague A or someone else sees that key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your vault would be being accessed over a network, so you would ask a colleague to use their own command line on their own workstation to enter their key. Mine requires 3 keys to unseal so I just have 3 users independently enter the `vault unseal` command with their key.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @alitheg answer, and to add two my cents, sequence of commands to be executed by you or any 3 colleagues of yours who has possession of the vault unseal token

```
export VAULT_ADDR=https://vault.yourcompany.com  # Address of your Vault
export VAULT_SKIP_VERIFY=true                    # this can be skipped, if you use a proper certificate and not self-signed certificate
vault status                                     # to check the vault status
vault unseal                                     # this will ask for the vault unseal token
```